# What the steps for creating, adding custom components and training a spaCy config file in SpaCy V3.6

Tags: python, nlp, config, spacy, spacy-3

For over a week I have been trying to do as the title explains. I have used to SpaCy documentation, spacy GitHub discussion, and google but I keep hitting road blocks. In theory this should be a simple process.

So far I have used this pages steps: https://spacy.io/usage/training/ and the given config file and this command:

```
python -m spacy init fill-config base_config.cfg config.cfg
```

**Currently I used this command to generate a new config:**

```
python -m spacy init config 'config\' --lang en --pipeline tok2vec,tagger,ner,parser,attribute_ruler,lemmatizer --optimize efficiency
```

that produced this config file:

```
[paths]
train = "output.spacy"
dev = "output.spacy"
vectors = null
init_tok2vec = null

[system]
gpu_allocator = null
seed = 0

[nlp]
lang = "en"
pipeline = ["tok2vec","tagger","ner","parser","attribute_ruler","lemmatizer"]
batch_size = 1000
disabled = []
before_creation = null
after_creation = null
after_pipeline_creation = null
tokenizer = {"@tokenizers":"spacy.Tokenizer.v1"}

[components]

[components.attribute_ruler]
factory = "attribute_ruler"
scorer = {"@scorers":"spacy.attribute_ruler_scorer.v1"}
validate = false

[components.lemmatizer]
factory = "lemmatizer"
mode = "rule"
model = null
overwrite = false
scorer = {"@scorers":"spacy.lemmatizer_scorer.v1"}

[components.ner]
factory = "ner"
incorrect_spans_key = null
moves = null
scorer = {"@scorers":"spacy.ner_scorer.v1"}
update_with_oracle_cut_size = 100

[components.ner.model]
@architectures = "spacy.TransitionBasedParser.v2"
state_type = "ner"
extra_state_tokens = false
hidden_width = 64
maxout_pieces = 2
use_upper = true
nO = null

[components.ner.model.tok2vec]
@architectures = "spacy.Tok2VecListener.v1"
width = ${components.tok2vec.model.encode.width}
upstream = "*"

[components.parser]
factory = "parser"
learn_tokens = false
min_action_freq = 30
moves = null
scorer = {"@scorers":"spacy.parser_scorer.v1"}
update_with_oracle_cut_size = 100

[components.parser.model]
@architectures = "spacy.TransitionBasedParser.v2"
state_type = "parser"
extra_state_tokens = false
hidden_width = 128
maxout_pieces = 3
use_upper = true
nO = null

[components.parser.model.tok2vec]
@architectures = "spacy.Tok2VecListener.v1"
width = ${components.tok2vec.model.encode.width}
upstream = "*"

[components.tagger]
factory = "tagger"
label_smoothing = 0.05
neg_prefix = "!"
overwrite = false
scorer = {"@scorers":"spacy.tagger_scorer.v1"}

[components.tagger.model]
@architectures = "spacy.Tagger.v2"
nO = null
normalize = false

[components.tagger.model.tok2vec]
@architectures = "spacy.Tok2VecListener.v1"
width = ${components.tok2vec.model.encode.width}
upstream = "*"

[components.tok2vec]
factory = "tok2vec"

[components.tok2vec.model]
@architectures = "spacy.Tok2Vec.v2"

[components.tok2vec.model.embed]
@architectures = "spacy.MultiHashEmbed.v2"
width = ${components.tok2vec.model.encode.width}
attrs = ["NORM","PREFIX","SUFFIX","SHAPE"]
rows = [5000,1000,2500,2500]
include_static_vectors = false

[components.tok2vec.model.encode]
@architectures = "spacy.MaxoutWindowEncoder.v2"
width = 96
depth = 4
window_size = 1
maxout_pieces = 3

[corpora]

[corpora.dev]
@readers = "spacy.Corpus.v1"
path = ${paths.dev}
max_length = 0
gold_preproc = false
limit = 0
augmenter = null

[corpora.train]
@readers = "spacy.Corpus.v1"
path = ${paths.train}
max_length = 0
gold_preproc = false
limit = 0
augmenter = null

[training]
dev_corpus = "corpora.dev"
train_corpus = "corpora.train"
seed = ${system.seed}
gpu_allocator = ${system.gpu_allocator}
dropout = 0.1
accumulate_gradient = 1
patience = 1600
max_epochs = 0
max_steps = 20000
eval_frequency = 200
frozen_components = []
annotating_components = []
before_to_disk = null
before_update = null

[training.batcher]
@batchers = "spacy.batch_by_words.v1"
discard_oversize = false
tolerance = 0.2
get_length = null

[training.batcher.size]
@schedules = "compounding.v1"
start = 100
stop = 1000
compound = 1.001
t = 0.0

[training.logger]
@loggers = "spacy.ConsoleLogger.v1"
progress_bar = false

[training.optimizer]
@optimizers = "Adam.v1"
beta1 = 0.9
beta2 = 0.999
L2_is_weight_decay = true
L2 = 0.01
grad_clip = 1.0
use_averages = false
eps = 0.00000001
learn_rate = 0.001

[training.score_weights]
tag_acc = 0.25
ents_f = 0.25
ents_p = 0.0
ents_r = 0.0
ents_per_type = null
dep_uas = 0.12
dep_las = 0.12
dep_las_per_type = null
sents_p = null
sents_r = null
sents_f = 0.0
lemma_acc = 0.25

[pretraining]

[initialize]
vectors = ${paths.vectors}
```

Using the debug command

```
python -m spacy debug data config2.cfg
```

I get this error:

```
Config validation error
vocab_data      field required
lookups field required
init_tok2vec    field required
tokenizer       field required
components      field required
before_init     field required
after_init      field required
{'vectors': None}
```

I have not had this error before and not sure how to get around it.
In addition, I still have the problem of adding in my custom components.
In past config files I have used to add in the custom components:

```
python -m spacy train 'config.cfg' --output 'config\' --code 'sentence.py', --code **'matcher.py'**
```

This does train the model ( when using a different config) but does not include the updated pipeline ( adds in 'sentencer' and 'matcher' )

This is the code for sentence.py:

```
import spacy
from spacy.language import Language
import re
from spacy.matcher import Matcher
from spacy.tokens import Token

@Language.component("sentence_splitter") # stateless
def sentence_splitter(doc):
    start = 0
    i = 0
    # print("Processing custom_sentence_splitter_improved")
    #delimiter_pattern = re.compile(r"(\r?\n)+|(\n)+")  # This is the magic regex
    delimiter_pattern = re.compile(r"(\r?\n\s*)+|(\n\s*)+")
    while i < len(doc):
        if delimiter_pattern.fullmatch(doc[i].text):
            # print(f"Found delimiter '{doc[i].text}' at position {i}")
            for token in doc[start:i]:
                token.sent_start = False
            doc[i].sent_start = True
            start = i + 1

            # Skip consecutive occurrences of '\r' and '\n'
            while i + 1 < len(doc) and delimiter_pattern.fullmatch(doc[i + 1].text):
                doc[i + 1].sent_start = False
                i += 1
        else:
            doc[i].sent_start = False
        i += 1

    for token in doc[start:]:
        token.sent_start = False

    return doc

# Used to add the custom component to the pipeline
nlp = spacy.load("en_core_web_lg")
nlp.add_pipe("sentence_splitter", name="sentence_splitter", after='ner')

#print(nlp.pipe_names)  # ['sentence_splitter', ...etc]
#doc = nlp("This is a sentence.")

tagger = nlp.create_pipe("tagger")
labels = {"LOGS": "LOGS", "EMAIL_SIG": "EMAIL_SIG"}
for label, description in labels.items():
    tagger.add_label(label, {"description": description})
nlp.add_pipe(tagger)
```

**Matcher.py:**

```
import spacy
from spacy.language import Language
import re
from spacy.matcher import Matcher
from spacy.tokens import Token

@Language.factory("matcher")# stateful
def create_template_matcher(nlp, name):
    return TemplateMatcher(nlp.vocab)

class TemplateMatcher:
    def __init__(self, vocab):
        # Define multiple patterns
        rma_patterns = [ # lots of patterns ]

        Token.set_extension("templates", default=False, force=True)  
# Register a new token extension to flag matched patterns
        self.matcher = Matcher(vocab)
        self.matcher.add("#1_PATTERNS", #1_PATTERNS)
        self.matcher.add("#2_PATTERNS", #2_PATTERNS)
        self.matcher.add("#3_PATTERNS", #3_PATTERNS)
        self.matcher.add("#4_PATTERNS", #4_PATTERNS)

    def __call__(self, doc):
        matches = self.matcher(doc)
        for match_id, start, end in matches:
            for token in doc[start:end]:
                token._.templates = True
        return doc

# Used to add the custom component to the pipeline
nlp = spacy.load("en_core_web_lg")
nlp.add_pipe("matcher", name="matcher", after ='attribute_ruler')

print(nlp.pipe_names)  # ['sentence_splitter', ...etc]
#doc = nlp("This is a sentence.")
```

Sorry, this is a long question.

**Perhaps to help me solve this problem it would be useful to have a definitive guide on:**

1. How to create a config file.
2. How to convert my spaCy annotations (standard spacy annotations format kept in a .py file) to .Spacy.
3. How to add in custom components

Specs:
SpaCy V3.6 with updated default models.
Python V3.11

Thank you so much!